# Enable-Mailbox cmdlet not finding correct Exchange 2007 database remotely

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've installed the 2007 Exchange remote management tools to manage Exchange on a Server 2008 64-bit box.  I'm having issues running the enable-mailbox command remotely, for some reason it's searching my local machine for the database rather than the Exchange database.  I attempt to run this command:

```
enable-mailbox -Identity Jordan -Database $database 

Database "someDomain\$database" was not found. Please make sure you have typed it correctly.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Mailbox
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
```

The database is actually located on `cas-exch.domain.centralazsupply.com`

The `$database` variable stores the object of the database that is retrieved using `get-mailboxdatabase.`, which returns the correct database.

I have no issues when running this command locally on the Exchange server.

Am I missing an additional parameter to specify the  location of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  If you're running this command remotely it looks like you need to use the `-DomainController` parameter and give it the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN).  The below command worked:

```
Enable-Mailbox -DomainController *domain here* -Database $database -Identity Jordan
```